# Problem with the schema structure produced by Schema module

Tags: 7, database, installation

I am using the Schema module (7.x-1.2) on Drupal 7.34. This is the code I am using for a module I created.

```php
function myid_schema(){
  $schema = array();    

  $schema['myid_templates'] = array(
    'description' => 'TODO: please describe this table!',
    'fields' => array(
      'template_id' => array(
        'description' => 'TODO: please describe this field!',
        'type' => 'serial',
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'template_name' => array(
        'description' => 'TODO: please describe this field!',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'not null' => FALSE,
      ),
      'portrait' => array(
        'description' => 'TODO: please describe this field!',
        'type' => 'boolean',
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
      'template_width' => array(
        'description' => 'TODO: please describe this field!',
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,
        'precision' => 0,
        'scale' => 0,
      ),
      'template_height' => array(
        'description' => 'TODO: please describe this field!',
        'type' => 'numeric',
        'not null' => TRUE,
        'default' => 0,
        'precision' => 0,
        'scale' => 0,
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('template_id'),
  );

  return $schema;
}

function myid_install() {
  drupal_install_schema('myid_templates');
}
```

After installing the module, it throws this error.

> Notice: Undefined index: boolean:normal in DatabaseSchema_pgsql->processField() (line 229 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal-7.34\includes\database\pgsql\schema.inc).
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: syntax error at or near "NOT" LINE 4: portrait NOT NULL, ^: CREATE TABLE {myid_templates} ( template_id serial, template_name varchar NULL, portrait NOT NULL, template_width numeric(0, 0) NOT NULL default 0, template_height numeric(0, 0) NOT NULL default 0, PRIMARY KEY (template_id) ); Array ( ) in db_create_table() (line 2720 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal-7.34\includes\database\database.inc)

Why does it throw an error? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal doesn't have a `boolean` type for DB schema, and there's no automatic fallback for a type it doesn't know about, so you end up with the invalid `portrait NOT NULL` instead of `portrait boolean NOT NULL` in the create statement.

To fix, just add a `pgsql_type` to the column. [`DatabaseSchema_pgsql::processField()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!pgsql!schema.inc/function/DatabaseSchema_pgsql%3A%3AprocessField/7.x) knows what to do with it.

```
'portrait' => array(
  'description' => 'TODO: please describe this field!',
  'type' => 'int', // Keep it portable
  'pgsql_type' => 'boolean',
  'not null' => TRUE,
),
```